# how to localize infoplist.strings for app bundle

Tags: macos, localization, for-loop

The question is we want to localize the bundleName and bundleDisplayName for bundle app, which means we already have a app bundle, in this bundle we only have english version, we want to have other language version. any solution? Many thanks first !

Answer (score 1):

Look here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingPathnames.html
under the header "Localizing Your Application Name".

Comment: let me clear my question, we can localize the bundle name and bundleDisplayName in xcode project before build, while what I want to do is we want to localize these name after the build, which means we already have a generated app bundle, we want to add localization manually, I create a folder zh-hans.lproj and copy InfoPlist.strings file from en.lproj and try to modify it, while this file is with mac os roman format, we find no methods to modify it, it that clear? Many thanks again!

Comment: Open the file in XCode and switch the File Encoding to UTF-16 by doing View->Text->File Encoding. Then, you should be able to add the Chinese text.